# Fleshing Out The Help Center

Tags: discussion

At the top of the [Help Center](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/help), there is a section  which can be edited and better spell out some of the dos and don'ts for MVM&R. I'd like to flesh this out with some areas where we don't take questions from, such as tire health, and make it a little more clear. All that is there right now are links to generic dos/don'ts from SE. I'd like to apply something a little closer to home. I'm hoping by adding some more detailed explanations as to why these things will get closed, it will help people not ask the questions in the first place. I realize the biggest question offender out there right now is tire health, so hopefully this will help.

To that end, I have an idea we should put a blurb about why tire health questions are off-topic. I'd also like to include as much as possible any other reason you all can think of, which has been vetted through our Meta, where people should not be asking questions of. I would include the big three which we have close reasons for already (shopping/price; driving techniques; tire health). I'd bet there are probably more.

Bottom line, I'm looking for a little help in this arena. Put your thoughts down as answers below and I'll start working on the text for it so we can get it in there.